# TvDatafeed.get_hist() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

import pandas as pd
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval
tv = TvDatafeed
symbols = ["NIFTY", "ITC"]

result = pd.concat([tv.get_hist(symbol=symbol,exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_5_minute,n_bars=5) for symbol in symbols])
result

#showing error>>
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 4>()
2 symbols = ["NIFTY", "ITC"]
3
----> 4 result = pd.concat([tv.get_hist(symbol=symbol,exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_5_minute,n_bars=5) for symbol in symbols])

<ipython****-input-43-e8f2b536adb5> in (.0)
2 symbols = ["NIFTY", "ITC"]
3
----> 4 result = pd.concat([tv.get_hist(symbol=symbol,exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_5_minute,n_bars=5) for symbol in symbols])

TypeError: TvDatafeed.get_hist() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

**plese help**

Comment: Please add an explanation of your issue rather than just sharing your code. Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and format your code properly.